# Where does this come from? or how do I derive it?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$\delta \vec{x} = \frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial r}\delta r + \frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \theta}\delta \theta+\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \phi}\delta \phi$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the chain rule. You have that $\vec{x}$ is a function of $(r,\theta.\phi)$, so that if we take a derivative of $\vec{x}$ with respect to some variable $t$, we have

$$
\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial r}\frac{dr}{dt}+\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}+\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \phi}\frac{d\phi}{dt}
$$

Thus, the first order taylor expansion for $\delta \vec{x}$ is

$$
\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial r}\delta r+\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \theta}\delta\theta+\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \phi}\delta\phi
$$

Comment: so like $\vec{x} + \vec{\delta x} = \vec{x} + \delta t \frac{d\vec{x}}{ dt} =\vec{x} + (\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial r}\delta r+\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \theta}\delta\theta+\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \phi}\delta\phi) $?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like.